# Subract and Add two columns from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I want to subract and add two columns from different table.

table book:

```
BookID | BookName | Author | Edition | PublishingYear | copies| Shelf | Row
   1   |   SQL    | Robert |    3    |     2005       | 3     |    A  |third
```

table Issue: (in this I have created join with tblPerson to show the PersonName instead of PersonID)

```
BookID | BookName | DateIssue  | ReturnDate | PersonName | copies
   1   |  SQL     | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-12 |     john   | 1
```

table Return:

```
BookID | BookName | DateIssue  | ReturnDate | PersonName | copies
   1   |  SQL     | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-12 |     john   | 1
```

Sql Query:

```
Select (tblBook.copies) - (tblIssue.copies)
FROm tblBook
FULL join tblIssue
ON tblBook.copies = tblIssue.copies
```

This query doesn't subract these two columns(copies).
I want to minus the column (copies) tblIssue from tblbook column copies(original value) when I issue the book.
And when I return the book from tbl Return, it gives me the original value in the column(copies) in tblBook.

Comment: seems you need to join on BookID instead of number of copies

Comment: `Select (tblBook.copies) - (tblIssue.copies)
FROm tblBook
FULL join tblIssue
ON tblBook.BookID = tblIssue.BookID`

Comment: BookID | BookName | DateIssue | ReturnDate | PersonName | copies 1 | SQL | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-12 | john | 1

Comment: @HaseebAsif want this output...

Comment: Why do you have 2 tables (issue, return) that have exact same contents? Shouldn't the issue have return date as null or status field for similar purpose, and then calculate only those rows

Comment: just add `select A.* from ...` rest of query will be same

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing joins, you need to join tables on they keys that binds the tables togheter.

Joining two tables on copies makes no logical sense, so instead join it on the primary key foreign key references BookID.

```
Select (tblBook.copies) - (tblIssue.copies)
FROm tblBook
FULL join tblIssue
ON tblBook.BookId = tblIssue.BookId
```

This will produce a following result, if no negations whas made.

```
BookID | BookName | Author | Edition | PublishingYear | copies| Shelf | Row | BookID | BookName | DateIssue  | ReturnDate | PersonName | copies
   1   |   SQL    | Robert |    3    |     2005       | 3     |    A  |third|    1   |  SQL     | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-12 |     john   | 1
```

Thereby subtracting `3-1` which should equal `2`. But it is always important to consider what the join result should be and then plan out your join strategy.

**EDIT 1**

An example query of how many books are availeble at given time

```
Select tblBook.BookId, MAX(tblBook.copies) - SUM(tblIssue.copies) as countOfAvailebleBooks
FROm tblBook
FULL join tblIssue
ON tblBook.BookId = tblIssue.BookId
WHERE tblIssue.ReturnDate >= '2015-10-12'AND tblIssue.IssueDate <= '2015-10-12'
```

This will produce an aggregate result for a given date, which is 2015-10-12 for this case, of how many books you are availeble, it is not optimal but what you have given, it seems like it is the best solution.

Comment: Actually this can be true if there is one to one relation. Else you will need some grouping with summing copies etc. But as OP did not provide any details, this is correct at the moment.

Comment: Your query is showing only copies column. I want to show with join Person Name and subraction in the copies column

Comment: BookID | BookName |  DateIssue   | ReturnDate  | PersonName | copies
   1       |  SQL           |  2015-10-12 | 2015-10-12 |     john            | 1

Comment: If you want that output where should the negation happen?

Comment: I think what you want to have is completely not needed in your use case, if you have a table for books, issues and returns, a library case you dont need to update the amount of books left but simply count them. But i think you need to update your question with what you actually wants, because it is at the moment quite confusing.

Comment: You r right !!! If somebody wants book and Issue one book. So, librarian can see in the book tbl that book is available or not by copies column.

Comment: Updated my answer, but i think you need to really consider you sql design, it seems like you have not figured out how to use your data, but my edit is a nice example of how you store rows and use aggregation instead of static values representing the availeble books.

Comment: It tells you how maby books are availeble you don't need the return table you already have the date in issues